# pass a parameter to an ajax callback

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a javascript function which must get a file and pass it with another parameter:

```
getJsonFile = function(fileName, callback, error, data) {
        var ajaxOptions = {
            url: util.pathJoin([Options.server_cache_path, jsonRelativeFileName]),
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(album) {
                callback(album, data)
            },
            error: error
        };
```

The `getJsonFile` function is called many times in `for` cycles throughout the application.

However, in the `callback` function, I sometimes find that the value of `data` is altered... Why does it happen? What's the solution?

Comment: Suspect you are using same `data` object reference each time. So order of responses is not guaranteed and if that object is modified the callback will see whatever last state of `data` object is. Show us sample of calling these in your loop and sample of `data`

Comment: Most likely `data` is an object or array and so is passed by reference. So it is being modified outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

As you described above, you are calling **getJsonFile** function from a loop (for) and most likely passing the **data** parameter as reference. In that scenario, you are passing a pointer to a variable which is changing in every loop iteration and by the time the **success** callback is invoked, **data** parameter has a reference to a different object from the original call.

One way to fix this kind of problems is to make copies of the parameters you received (or at least from **data**) **OR** capture the value you are interested in using a closure to capture the current **data** referenced value.

```
getJsonFile = function(fileName, callback, error, data) {
        var callbackCall = (function(myData) { 
            return function(myAlbum) { callback(myAlbum, myData); };
        })(data);
        var ajaxOptions = {
            url: util.pathJoin([Options.server_cache_path, jsonRelativeFileName]),
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(album) {
                callbackCall(album);
            },
            error: error
        };
```

Avoiding the callbackCall variable

```
getJsonFile = function(fileName, callback, error, data) {
   // Code omitted...
   success: (function(myData) { 
            return function(album) { callback(album, myData); };
   })(data)
   // Code omitted...
}
```

Comment: A closure won't copy the data object, it just keeps a reference to it, as you said, so this won't prevent the problem OP seems to be having. You are correct about copying the object though. OP could also pass (or destructure) a primitive value from the data object too.

Comment: @chipit24 You may be right, but (as I stated in the answer) I assumed the problem is the reference being modified in the the loop, but if the object is being mutated on other parts of the application, your suggestion on destructuring the object or making a copy of it (shallow copy?) might be the  solution at the end. Thanks for the observations.